# Writing to a file not working in Raspberry Pi using Terminal

Tags: python, raspberry-pi2

I will try and keep it short
I just got a Raspberry Pi and I am trying to write to a file using Python. I wrote this small program that gets input from the user and it will be put in a text file.

```
# Grabs a line from user input and saves it to a file
import sys

for line in sys.stdin:
   file = open('notes.txt', 'a')
   file.write(line)
   file.close()
```

I tried running this in a Python shell and it works fine. But, when I tried running it in terminal, using python/python3 test.py, it didn't work.

Am I doing something wrong?
Thanks

Comment: You can use input/raw_input if you want to take input from the user, you should also open the file once outside the loop.

Answer (score 2):

its expecting stdin

```
 $ python notes.py <<< this is a bunch of stdin input that will be saved in notes.txt
```

(not sure how many < to use off hand ... 1, 2, or 3)

perhaps instead you want to use

```
with open("notes.txt","a") as f:
     for line in iter(raw_input,""): #in py3 just use `input`
         f.write(line+"\n")
```

which will prompt for input

Comment: I have a feeling the second option is what the OP wants, sometimes you don't know what you want until someone tells you ;)

Comment: Thanks, I used raw_input instead.
I used
[code]
while True:
   line = raw_input()
   file = open('notes.txt', 'a')
   file.write(line+"\n")
   file.close()
[/code]

Comment: @JaredFisher, your while loop will never end unless you end the script, you should also not be continuously opening it inside the loop. Open it once outside as Joran has.